# counting total rows in sql lite

Tags: android, sqlite

I wrote a method in my database manager that is suppose to return the total amount of rows in a table called homeIcons;  but i noticed that it returns 0 when there are 0, 1 there is 1, and then 10 when there are 3?  so something is wrong with my method..  please see below:

```
public int getHomeScreenTotal (){

        SQLiteDatabase db=this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor c = db.rawQuery("select count(*) as count from "+ homeIcons,null);
        c.moveToFirst();
        int total = c.getInt(0);
        return total; 

}
```

*EDIT*
so i edited my code.. and i have rewritten this method in just about every way possible.. The problem is not that it isn't returning the right amount of rows, because it is.. it is just that it is returning the number in binary..  instead of 3, it returns 11  instead of 5 it returns 101 .. UHG!!!!  i just want an int!  I can't tell if this is a bug in the adroid/java method for accessing a SQLite DB or if i am missing something.. I have even tried duck punching it to an int, but to no avail..  :(

*EDIT*
ok i just tried to force the binary to an int using the following method:

```
public int getHomeScreenTotal (){

        SQLiteDatabase db=this.getReadableDatabase();
        int rows;

        String bin = ""+ db.compileStatement("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM " + homeIcons).simpleQueryForLong();

        rows = Integer.parseInt(bin, 2);
        return rows;


    }
```

this throws an Error of

*java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: "7"*

where the "7" is, is actually the number it is suppose to return..  if i have 5 rows i get an error of Invalid int "5"; ect..

Comment: Please make sure to close your cursor before returning from your method

Comment: I should close my cursor correct.. The problem seems to be that the count is long and i need an int.. I tried forcing it as an int but im still getting binary returns like 1, 10,11, 100,101 instead of 1,2, 3,4

Answer (score 3):

You'll be much happier making the database do the lifting for you.

```
String query = "select count(*) from " + homeIcons;
```

Comment: Agreed. Never use cursors when there is set based logic that can get the same result

Answer (score 0):

you can get the number of rows from SQLite by executing the following query:

```
SELECT count(*) as count FROM homeIcons;
```

it will return a table containing one row, which contains only the number of rows in your `homeIcons` table:

```
+---------+
|  count  |
+---------+
|   ###   |
+---------+
```

To use this code in your application, execute:

```
Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT count(*) AS count FROM "+ homeIcons,null);
c.moveToFirst();
int total = c.getInt(0);
```

**EDIT**

to get the decimal number out of the binary that is returned, use:

```
String bin = "" + c.getInt(0);
int total = Integer.parseInt(bin, 2);
```

Comment: Im doing this in java for android.. If i am not using a Cursor, how do i return an int with the value of number of rows found..

Comment: @erik This does not always return 1 if executed properly.  If that is what you are getting, you have another problem somewhere else.  Note that the above query is raw SQL, not Java code for executing that query.

Comment: @erik.  sorry about the PHP post, I was confusing this with a different question. :-)

Comment: I think its returning a 1 because it is using Cursor getcount.. i edited my code above..  I guess my question is for a Java/Android Developer.. this method is in my DataBaseManager class

Comment: I don't know much about android db, but I would guess replace `getCount()` with `getInt(0)`.  I answered in the first place because I figured letting SQL do the calculation would be better form than trying to do it through java.

Comment: @erik I think I figured it out.  Try `c.moveToFirst();`, before you execute `c.getInt(0);`.  That worked for me.  Seems to imply that the Cursor object gets returned pointing to the end of the table, and you have to move it back to the beginning to retrieve values

Comment: was a step ahead of you.. but still a problem  see EDIT above..thanks for your continued support in this trying time when all i want is an int and im getting binary..  :(

Comment: Id be happy to upvote you, but my problem is still not solved

Comment: @erik did `parseInt` not work?  If you are getting a binary string every time, then there is no reason that it wouldnt.  Regardless, the issue with the binary numbers is most likely a setting in your database

Comment: @erik At this point, I would actually recommend that you close out this question, as it has begun to veer off the original topic.  The original problem of retrieving the number of rows has been solved.  I suggest you open a new question to discuss why you are getting binary numbers. Keep in mind that the title of this post is no longer valid.

Comment: my appologies..  I guess, i just saw it as the same problem.. i also missed your edit using parseInt.  i just tried that and it returned an error ofjava.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid radix: 2

Comment: @erik there's gotta be something wrong with your install of Java then.  There is literally no reason that it should not be able to handle that call.  what version of java are you running?

Comment: Java version 1.6.0_26 from apple

Comment: @erik hmmm... This definitely warrants a separate question.  I can only imagine there's something wrong with your java install